# How to have a tooltip-like element appear after a few seconds of hovering above a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make it such that after about 3 seconds of a user hovering above a button, a tooltip-like element would appear to it's right.
For instance, a user to hover over a button for a few seconds and the description would fade in to the button's right, then would fade out when the user takes the mouse off the button.

I have tried `:hover` in CSS and the `onmouseover` attribute, but I really don't know what to do.

I am sorry if there is too little information or examples, but I would really like a solution.

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are many basic examples of tooltip functionality available online by searching for `css tooltip`. Do you have any existing HTML/CSS as an example? You likely don't need JS for something like this.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to make the tooltip fade in after a certain amount of time has passed.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-delay

Answer (score 2):

What about a `CSS` only approach ? The idea is to fade in some text after some delay and yes `CSS` can do it.

```css
button {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin: 15px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: #cecece;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .4s 0s ease;
}

button,
button:before,
button:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #bababa;
}

button:hover:before,
button:hover:after {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.4s 3s ease; /** that's the magic **/
}

button:before,
button:after {
  content: "";
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0);
  transition: all 0.4s 0s ease;
}

button:before {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  right: -8px;
  border: 8px solid transparent;
  border-right-color: #181818;
}

button:after {
  content: attr(aria-label);
  width: 100%;
  left: calc(100% + 8px);
  padding: 6px;
  background-color: #181818;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<!-- the content of aria-label attribute is the text that will be shown -->
<button type="button" aria-label="lorem ipsum sit dolor amet.">Hover Over Me (3s)</button>
```

> Anyway, there are many `CSS` only tooltip libraries out there that i'd suggest checking them.
>
> Feel free to ask for clarifications.

Comment: Thank you, but if somebody were to spam click the button continuously, it would still show the text after 3 seconds, which I do not want to happen. Is there a solution to that?

Comment: @SomeRandomCoder - yes, there's a solution. Have a class on the button e.g. `<button class="tippable">` and include that class in the CSS that gives you the tooltip effect. When the thing (button in this case) is clicked remove the class on it, and the tooltip will no longer happen. You could even put the class back on it later (say, after a timeout?) to restore the tooltip effect.

Comment: @StephenP yes it could work but it's not a `CSS` only approach (as what my answer is aiming to accomplish).

Comment: @StephenP, so what I did was using classList.remove() to remove the class and added this: setTimeout(function(){ [the button thing].classList.add(the original class name); }, 3000);  , but if I was to spam click it, it would still show weird results. Could you help me?

Comment: @SomeRandomCoder That wouldn't be an answer to _this_ question and comments aren't for extended discussion — I think that should be a new question.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const tooltip = document.querySelector(".tooltip");
const hoverMe = document.querySelector(".hover-me");
let timeout;

const showTooltip = () => {
  tooltip.style.display = "block";
  timeout = undefined;
}

const hideTooltip = () => {
  tooltip.style.display = "none";
  if (timeout) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = undefined;
  }
}

hoverMe.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
  timeout = setTimeout(showTooltip, 3000);
});

hoverMe.addEventListener("click", hideTooltip);

hoverMe.addEventListener("mouseout", hideTooltip)
```

```html
<div class="hover-me"> Hover me</div>

<div class="tooltip" style="display: none">I'm a tooltip</div>
```

You can set a timeout and clear it if you don't want it to finish executing.